# Errors with summarise function

Tags: r

My data frame is reproduced at the bottom of this question. Please excuse me if it does not work, I have not used dput() before!

I am trying to aggregate the participants of my dataframe by their highest level of activity. I wrote the following summarise function:

```
activitylevel_groups <- summarise(total_merge,
                                 activity_level = (factor(case_when(
                                     sedentary_minutes > mean(sedentary_minutes) & lightly_active_minutes < mean(lightly_active_minutes) & moderately_active_minutes < mean(moderately_active_minutes) & very_active_minutes < mean(very_active_minutes) ~ "Sedentary",
                                     sedentary_minutes < mean(sedentary_minutes) & lightly_active_minutes > mean(lightly_active_minutes) & moderately_active_minutes < mean(moderately_active_minutes) & very_active_minutes < mean(very_active_minutes) ~ "Lightly Active",
                                     sedentary_minutes < mean(sedentary_minutes) & lightly_active_minutes < mean(lightly_active_minutes) & moderately_active_minutes > mean(moderately_active_minutes) & very_active_minutes < mean(very_active_minutes) ~ "Moderately Active",
                                     sedentary_minutes < mean(sedentary_minutes) & lightly_active_minutes < mean(lightly_active_minutes) & moderately_active_minutes < mean(moderately_active_minutes) & very_active_minutes > mean(very_active_minutes) ~ "Very Active",))),
                                 levels = c("Sedentary", "Lightly Active", "Moderately Active", "Very Active"),
                                 calories,
                                 .group = id)
```

I have been getting the following error back:

`Problem while recycling levels = c("Sedentary", "Lightly Active", "Moderately Active", "Very Active"). ✖ levels must be size 3362 or 1, not 4.`

How can I get the function to organize the participants by their activity level based on the terms I laid out in my function?

Data:

```
    activity_df <- structure(list(id = c("p01", "p01", "p01", "p01", "p01", "p01", 
"p01", "p01", "p01", "p01", "p01", "p01", "p01", "p01", "p01", 
"p01", "p01", "p01", "p01", "p01"), date = structure(c(1572566400, 
1572652800, 1572739200, 1572825600, 1572912000, 1572998400, 1573084800, 
1573084800, 1573171200, 1573257600, 1573344000, 1573430400, 1573516800, 
1573603200, 1573689600, 1573776000, 1573862400, 1573948800, 1574035200, 
1574121600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), calories = c(4009.94, 
3551.36, 3732.46, 3391.45, 3896.41, 3050.33, 3144.57, 3144.57, 
3659.01, 3906.06, 4023.01, 3594.91, 3408.16, 3302.9, 4545, 4194.29, 
3998.97, 3482.54, 3389.12, 2975.27), sedentary_minutes = c(636L, 
709L, 648L, 760L, 737L, 849L, 866L, 866L, 744L, 653L, 629L, 811L, 
744L, 825L, 691L, 660L, 668L, 752L, 878L, 903L), lightly_active_minutes = c(245L, 
202L, 262L, 230L, 263L, 206L, 182L, 182L, 212L, 305L, 263L, 220L, 
221L, 197L, 208L, 265L, 302L, 248L, 131L, 145L), moderately_active_minutes = c(58L, 
43L, 63L, 23L, 22L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 38L, 31L, 34L, 13L, 16L, 24L, 
53L, 45L, 47L, 28L, 4L, 6L), very_active_minutes = c(72L, 56L, 
45L, 28L, 56L, 11L, 15L, 15L, 54L, 60L, 92L, 40L, 36L, 33L, 121L, 
85L, 64L, 35L, 55L, 25L), steps = c(17873L, 13118L, 14312L, 10970L, 
16186L, 8189L, 8710L, 8710L, 12888L, 16450L, 17843L, 12519L, 
10392L, 11185L, 19220L, 18259L, 15305L, 11916L, 8241L, 7134L), 
    time_in_bed = c(NA, 430L, 422L, 399L, 362L, 364L, 366L, 366L, 
    392L, 391L, 422L, 356L, 423L, 361L, 367L, 385L, 359L, 377L, 
    372L, 361L), minutes_asleep = c(NA, 378L, 378L, 361L, 326L, 
    341L, 312L, 312L, 360L, 344L, 382L, 318L, 378L, 320L, 325L, 
    342L, 317L, 337L, 330L, 318L)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Your parentheses aren't balancing, that's the problem. Notice the hanging comma after "very active", and also that you have enough parentheses afterwards such that "levels" is an argument for summarize instead of for factor.

Also I think you want mutate instead of summarize to make the new variable here. Afterwards you can group_by(activity_level) and summarize to summarize it if you want

Comment: Beyond the coding errors, there are 16 combinations of TRUE / FALSE values for the four levels of activity, not 4. Therefore, the `case_when()` logic in the question is going to generate a lot of NA values for `activity_level`.  For example, how should the code classify a row where multiple columns are above their mean for a given individual?

Comment: Thanks for these pointers, both the internal logic of my case_when and my code had some issues.  Simplifying my boolean arguments and making sure all my functions were in the right parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure I fully understood the question, I think it would have been better to have a few more ID's in the DF, but something like this may work:

```
library(tidyverse)

activitylevel_groups <- activity_df %>% 
  mutate(
    activity_level = case_when(
      sedentary_minutes > mean(sedentary_minutes)  ~ "Sedentary",
      lightly_active_minutes > mean(lightly_active_minutes) ~ "Lightly Active",
      moderately_active_minutes > mean(moderately_active_minutes) ~ "Moderately Active",
      very_active_minutes > mean(very_active_minutes) ~ "Very Active",
      TRUE ~ "other")
    ) %>% 
  group_by(id,activity_level) %>% 
  summarise(
    activity_level_days = n()
    )
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   id [1]
  id    activity_level    activity_level_days
  <chr> <chr>                           <int>
1 p01   Lightly Active                      7
2 p01   Moderately Active                   3
3 p01   other                               1
4 p01   Sedentary                           9
```

I think your case_when needed a bit of work in the mutate - I'm not 100% sure its giving you the bands you need now I have altered it. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me think about how to stack my different functions inside of each other!